# Quickest way to remove 70+ strings from a file?

Tags: linux, sed

I have 70+ strings I need to find and delete in a file. I need to remove the entire line in the file that the string appears in.

I know I can use `sed -i '/string to remove/d' fileA.txt` to remove them one at a time. However, considering I have 70+, it will take some time doing it this way.

Is there a way I can put these 70+ strings in a file and have sed go through them one by one? Or if I create a file containing the strings, is there a way to compare the two files so it removes any line from fileA that contains one of the strings?

Answer (score 5):

You could use `grep`:

```
grep -vf file_with_words.txt file.txt
```

where `file_with_words.txt` would be the file containing the list of words, each word being on a different line and `file.txt` is the file that you want to remove the lines from.

If your list of words contains regex metacharacters, then tell `grep` to consider those as fixed strings (if that is what you want):

```
grep -F -vf file_with_words.txt file.txt
```

---

Using `sed`, you'd need to say:

```
sed '/word1\|word2\|word3/d' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -E '/word1|word2|word3/d' file.txt
```

You could use command substitution to construct the pattern too:

```
sed -E "/$(paste -sd'|' file_with_words.txt)/d" file.txt
```

but `grep` is clearly the tool to use in this case.

Comment: So I tried this:

grep -vf file_with_words.txt file.txt

It doesn't modify file.txt. I get a printout of the file.txt. Does it not modify the file and just print out file.txt without the strings from file_with_words?

Comment: Okay, so I tried this:
 
grep -vf file_with_words.txt file.txt >> newfile.txt. That seems to have worked.

Comment: `grep` does perform any change to the file.  You'd need to redirect the output to another file.

Comment: Is it possible to 'and' this command with another string? For example, I want to remove all the strings that show up in file_with_words.txt but only if the line contains the string 'xyz' as well.

Comment: @Khan One way would be `grep -q 'xyz' file.txt && grep -vf file_with_words.txt file.txt` -- You could replace the part after `&&` in this command with any of the commands in the answer above that work the best for you.

Comment: How is the syntax for this working?

sed -E "/$(paste -sd'|' file_with_words.txt)/d" file.txt.

You use the double quotes there because you're using a variable. But why are there single quotes in the middle?

Comment: @Khan Regarding your first question: The `|` in single quotes is the delimiter for `paste`.  Regarding your other question(s), may I request you to post a new question instead.  Comments are best utilized for clarifications.  Follow up questions are best asked in a different post.  (Moreover, comments suffer from readability and formatting limitations.)

Comment: @Khan The double quotes are for the command substitution syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the job in bash, here's how:

```
search=fileA.txt

queries=queries.txt

while read query
do
    sed  -i '' "/$query/d" $search
done < "$queries"
```

where queries.txt looks like

```
I
want
to
delete
these
lines
```